# How can this trig equation be simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

We have $9+40\sin^2x=-42\sin x\cos x$.

I know this simplifies to $7\sin x+3\cos x=0$, but how?

Comment: Try using $\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$.

Comment: @IanColey Nice approach, but there is the user who provided the hint already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Along with Trafalgar Law's hint, we can use the fact that $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1$.  Multiply both sides by $9$ to get $9 = 9\sin^2(x) + 9\cos^2(x)$.  We then have

$$\begin{aligned}
9\sin^2(x) + 9\cos^2(x) + 40\sin^2(x) &= -42\sin(x)\cos(x)\\
49\sin^2(x) + 42\sin(x)\cos(x) + 9\cos^2(x) &= 0\\
(7\sin(x) + 3\cos(x))^2 &= 0
\end{aligned}$$

which gives the desirable equation you want to have.

Comment: Hehe.  Changed back to before.

Answer (score 7):

Hint : write $9 = 9\sin^2(x)+9\cos^2(x)$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

When you have only terms like $\sin^2x,\cos^2x,\sin x\cos x$

divide either sides by $\cos^2x,$

$$9\sec^2x+40\tan^2x=-42\tan x\iff9(1+\tan^2x)+40\tan^2x=-42\tan x$$

$$\iff49\tan^2x-42\tan x+9=0$$ which is a Quadratic Equation in $\tan x$